# Mamzer or not? Food for thought

Tags: halacha, zohar, mamzer

In the Me'am Loez the first book, (Genesis I) towards the end of the book it talks about the woman that had relations with their husbands while thinking of the nephilim, giving the child's neshama a touch of mamzerut.

From Halachic point of view is the child a mamzer or not?

I would have to say yes, a child born from a typical mazer situation the only reason the child is a mamzer is due to the fact the child's neshama came from another man that is not the father.

So in the above case, what would be the difference?

Comment: What makes you think the source of one's neshama has any bearing on halacha?

Comment: "... _the only reason the child is a mamzer is due to the fact the childs neshama came from another man that is not the father._" Doesn't [a child's neshama come from God](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Niddah.31a.9?lang=bi&lang2=en)?

Comment: @Shmosel,   nothing to do with the imagination or the hippy understanding of the neshama. The book also explains how Yaakove manipulated the thoughts of the sheep to bring different sheep, so I with this sense you can see the even WHEN the proper male mated, the child is not the son. Not only that there are many sources that explain how even though through the regular marriage when kids don't behave like their parents is became they are not. I believe there's an actual galactic debate about this. I have to find.

Answer (score 4):

Halachically, it has no impact whatsoever on one's status.

However, spiritually, it could impact one's offspring's spiritual connection and "health".
There is a story with the Maggid of Mezeritch where a father came to complain to him that his son ran away with a non Jewish woman. The Maggid said to him that if he had not improperly fantasized about his non Jewish neighbor while conceiving that same son with his wife, this would have not happened.

I could find sources on how it is so according to Kabbalah, I may eventually edit or add a response.

Comment: Excellent answer and story. No need to put the kaballah of this on the open internet, there's an explicit Gemarra on this exact topic

Comment: @avraham. I would love to see the sources from kaballah. If you could please do so that would be amazing! Thank you.

Comment: @יהושעק. What sources do you have from the Gemara?! If you could share that would be amazing, thank you in advance.

Comment: @Gabriel the easy one is Brachot 20A with rebbi Yochanan hanging out outside the mikvah so women will see him and have children as beautiful as him :https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.20a.7?lang=bi ....there's another one where a couple has a picture of an African man in their bedroom and the baby comes out black though the mother was never unfaithful to her husband and the Gemarra explains she was looking at the picture, but I can't locate it right now

Comment: @יהושעק     This is very disturbing, to know. ill have to read it again.     The African version I have heard it before.        Well, there you go, the point of sexual purity is not only in the mikve, also in the thoughts while in the moment.

Comment: @Gabriel a good starting point would be the Or Hachaim Hakadosh on Parshat Tazria at the beginning. He also brings there the Zohar on Parshat Kedoshim Daf 80. There is a book authored by the Matok MiDvash (Rabbi Daniel Frisch Zt"l) named Sefer Kedushah VeTzniyut, at beginning of chapter 12 where he elaborates on the importance of having pure thought during the intercourse, and its damages if we do not.

Comment: @Avraham, Unfortunately I'm unable to find the   Or Hachaim Hakadosh, and Matok MiDvash, Sefer Kedushah VeTzniyut. Do you have any links that I may use?